# Git object database seems to be missing blob objects

Tags: git, github, version-control, tree

Based on [this article from Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects), where objects and how they are stored are explained, I am looking at our Git repository objects, and I think that either Git stores things a little bit differently, or not storing everything.

### Background

According to the article, there are object types such as `tree`, `commit`, and `blob`:

1. `blob` is simply a file.
2. `tree` is like container object, in its content, it has SHA-1 hash codes which references either a sub tree or other blob objects.
3. `commit` contains a `tree` references as well as information about the author, time, etc.

So far so good.

### Our Source Code

Our source code contains hundred of folders, thousands of files, etc. And we pretty much add everything to the source control.

### The Problem

When I run the following command: `find .git/objects -type f`, I get the following result:

[image]

They are the only objects I can see, which contains `commit`, `tree`, and `blobs`.

Let's check the content of a sample object from that list by running this command `git cat-file -p 04acc15d91xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`:

[image]

If you like the types in the content of a taken `tree` object, we see that it references three `tree` object and two `blob` objects. And the blobs as you see have names ending with various extensions, and they are actual files in my source code folder.

But when thinking about the number of files we have, the amount of objects is not matching. There are way too few objects in the object list. **Where are those other `blob` objects?**

Also, when I say `$ git cat-file -p e57531c55xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` on a `blob` object, I get the same content as if I was opening the file with a text editor, which is expected:

[image]

This is good and all. While everything is working as expected. Then, where are the rest of the `blob` objects?

Also, when I look at a tree object with sub-trees, I see the same folder structure that I see in my working directory, which is also expected according to this paragraph from the same page:

> Git stores content in a manner similar to a UNIX filesystem, but a bit
> simplified. **All the content is stored as tree and blob objects, with
> trees corresponding to UNIX directory entries and blobs corresponding
> more or less to inodes or file contents.** A single tree object contains
> one or more tree entries, each of which contains a SHA-1 pointer to a
> blob or subtree with its associated mode, type, and filename.

I feel like, at some point, Git stops creating trees for folders and store them as big blobs(?).

Comment: You just need to advance two subsections further, to https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles.  See also various SO answers about "loose" vs "packed" objects.

Comment: Those "big blobs" as you say in the last paragraph are in fact pack files. We can see them in the topmost screenshot, at the bottom, mostly masked out by your blurring but you can clearly see the pack file index and the pack file itself at the bottom. Multiple other git objects have been combined into this pack file.

Comment: If you execute `git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-SHA.pack` you can see its contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You feel like there are missing Git object files on disk because you're both right and wrong.

They're no longer on disk as *separate files*, but they have been combined into a pack file.

So they are on disk, just not in separate files.

You can see this pack file at the bottom of your topmost screenshot. A pack file is a `.pack` file along with a `.idx`, the index of the pack file.

You can look inside the pack file by executing this command:

```
git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-SHA-OF-PACK.pack
```

This should list something like:

```
200c8213bd227eed106fed7b168ac3dfd5257cc3 commit 263 184 12
b8043e69c7af9925e3a52500ab26cc743ff5ef5f commit 458 293 196
...
non delta: 311 objects
chain length = 1: 194 objects
...
.git\objects\pack\pack-SHA....pack: ok
```

*(This knowledge and the example listing above is taken from this page: *[Unpacking Git packfiles](https://codewords.recurse.com/issues/three/unpacking-git-packfiles)*)*

So what if you really think your repository is borked? That it really is missing files? Well, then you would ask git to verify the structure and contents of your Git repository with this:

```
git fsck
```

This command will output something like this:

```
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (890/890), done.
```

Note that if you have deleted branches, rebased, or done other history rewriting commands you will likely see lines like this as well:

```
dangling blob f7f7076e53ec9d5a7bde5dcac55af66ea269a5d0
dangling blob f837cd05aa401ba36b1a41a6cc7e7e87c25c0ae3
```

Dangling blobs are *benign* in the sense that these are no longer referenced by any branch, tag, HEAD, or similar and will eventually be pruned. If, on the other hand, you're really missing commits, like if you deleted a branch by mistake, then these hashes might give you back your content.